# How to detect possible fraudulent administration of a survey questionnaire?

Tags: survey, fraud-detection

I'm involved in a survey on a highly sensitive topic, where I have reason to believe that the subcontractor who was responsible for data collection (a call centre) may have been pressured / paid / similar to produce fraudulent data that paints a powerful individual in a positive light.

Is there any way to detect whether responses to three multiple choice questions may have been entered fraudulently? Are there any recognised techniques for doing this?

The full survey has around 30 questions, it is administered to a panel that we contact once each month with a different survey. We have asked the same (and other similar) sensitive questions before (in earlier years, to the same panel). The results this year are strikingly different compared to 2018, 2017 and so on - which is part of the reason for my concern.

Comment: You can use previous historic data to build priors, and then check how different this year's results are compared to your beliefs.